# Why isn't this SQL statement working? Is it a problem with my MariaDB server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ghost-blog

This has been a frustrating issue. On my Linux machine (hold up, don't transfer me to AskUbuntu yet), I install my [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/) server (`sudo apt install mysql-server`), and login with `sudo mysql -uroot -p`,and type in my password. Here's the weird part. I enter in my statement, which is below.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypasswordhere';
```

At which point I get the standard 'please check the docs that correspond with your MariaDB server', which I am sure drives every programmer insane at some point. The bigger issue is, this statement is recorded in official documentation for a [service I am using](https://docs.ghost.org/install/ubuntu/#mysql-on-ubuntu-1804). Any help is greatly appreciated. If there *is* a problem with my statement, please let me know.

Comment: What version of MariaDB/MySQL?  This statement has had some recent changes; you may be using a version that does not yet support the statement.  Check the docs for _your_ version.

Comment: @RickJames I installed the latest

Comment: According to the latest documentation ( https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/ ) you should be able to run `ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswordhere';` ... mind giving it a try?

Comment: @AlexandreVoyer, Hmmmm.... not working. Same error

Comment: 10.1.37-MariaDB on Windows 8 I get this message `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'user2'@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypasswordhere'' at line 1`. I have another 10.3.10-MariaDB-log running on Windows Server 2012 and I get a slightly different error message `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'mypasswordhere'' at line 1`. So, which version are you?

Comment: When running this `ALTER USER user2@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswordhere';` on 10.1.37-MariaDB it failed at same position with the first query, at `'USER ... `. While it run successfully on 10.3.10-MariaDB-log.

Comment: Run [SHOW PLUGINS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-plugins/) to see if `mysql_native_password` is there.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I run Raspbian, and I get the first message

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, it is there

Comment: The ALTER USER statement was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I'll try to upgrade, but I'm having trouble with it. Is there a rock solid way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/):

> The ALTER USER statement was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

Upgrade to a version equals or higher to 10.2.0 and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Is there an easy way to upgrade on a distro like Raspbian? Other than manually building and compiling the source?

Comment: No need to build it yourself. Use a package : https://howtoraspberrypi.com/mariadb-raspbian-raspberry-pi/